# RestSharp.Portable HttpRequestException 500 (Internal Server Error) on iOS POST Request

Tags: ios, web-services, rest, xamarin, restsharp

I am using the [RestSharp.Portable](https://github.com/FubarDevelopment/restsharp.portable) PCL because I am building a cross-platform service manager that will wrap and make calls to RestSharp regardless of the platform I am on.

I am trying to POST data using a Xamarin iOS unit test project and I can successfully make GET requests but when I try to do a POST it always fails. My web service also has Swagger documentation and I was able to POST data using that but never with this library. Is this a good example of how to call it for a POST request?

When the client.Execute() method is invoked, it returns the error below. I also verified no network traffic occurs from the mobile client when proxying through Fiddler so it must be failing before it ever leaves the device.

```
var payload = new User()
{
    FirstName ="Suzy",
    LastName = "Q",
    Age = 43
};

using (var client = new RestClient("http://mywebservice.com:8308"))
{
    var request = new RestRequest("api/Accounts/Register", HttpMethod.Post);
    request.AddJsonBody (payload);
    var result = await client.Execute<UserRegistrationResponse>(request);
    var userId = result.Data.UserId;
}
```

[image: ios simulator screen shot jun 1 2015 10 46 06 am]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opened GitHub issue here for reference:

https://github.com/FubarDevelopment/restsharp.portable/issues/31